# Displaying an image according to multiple values

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to load an image based on a set of options. Say a user selects a product with the color blue. An image will load of a blue colored product. Then, say a user selects a rough finish. An image will load showing a blue product with a rough finish. I don't want to have one dropdown with all product combinations because that would be in the hundreds. I would rather it be carousels or galleries for each products variable (color, finish, size, etc) that would combine their values to display one image.

Has any one seen anything like this before and can point me in the direction of a solution?

*edit* - This site kind of does what I'm talking about. http://www.troveline.com/windowfilm_order.php4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a basic example of how you could build a URL via select boxes and jquery here: http://jsfiddle.net/daybreaker/pdhzb/

The only downfall is you need to make sure you set the value for the default select to something like "none", and that you then need to have an image defined for every possible combination of select boxes... like:

```
blue-none-none.jpg
blue-rough-none.jpg
blue-smooth-none.jpg
blue-rough-small.jpg
blue-rough-large.jpg
blue-smooth-small.jpg
blue-smooth-large.jpg
blue-none-small.jpg
blue-none-large.jpg
red-none-none.jpg ...etc
```

Another option is to have a database table of products, with an associated table called "options", and then your jQuery could submit an ajax request that sends your select options to a page that does a query to find an item that has all the options listed, then returns the HTML for its image.

```
$.post('find_image.php',$("#form_name").serialize(),function(data){
    $('span#img').html(data); // If find_image.php return <img src="image.php">
});
```

Comment: Any advice on using alternate methods to switch one of the values. A carousel perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

i would use radio buttons with and javascript with a HUGE [multidimensional array](http://www.kavoir.com/2009/02/javascript-multi-dimensional-array.html) of image urls. shouldn't be to hard, just alot of work. And use tons of css.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what server-side language you use, but Microsoft has something for sorting out massive number of images:

http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/pivotviewer/

Check the Interactive Demos to see if it fits your need.